# How to avoid page break in table with rowspan on print

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have problem when printing my page which contain table in html. It's break into new page even it's still inside the same row. How do i prevent this?

This is how my print preview looks like.

[image: this is how my print preview looks like]

Comment: Printer does not see your elements, so you must manually decide where page break will be and there create new table with rest of data

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media print {
    tr {
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    }
}
```